# Get cleaned_data from queryset

Tags: python, django

Hi How can I get cleaned data from a queryset?
And can I use .split() on an queryset?

Ex.

```
CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True)
```

The code above prints this:

```
<bound method QuerySet.last of <QuerySet [4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 14, 10, 12]>>  # need last number (12)
```

But I only need the *number 12* (the newest/latest number added to the model)
I tried using **.cleaned_data** to only get the numbers (without <QuerySet etc.) and **.split**.

I need the number 12 for a while loop.

Edit: The Model where the number is saved in:

```
class CartQuantity(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    cquantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CartQuantity matching query does not exist ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66053178/cartquantity-matching-query-does-not-exist-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True)[-1]`

should give you the last item in the queryset.

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: I get an error: store.models.CartQuantity.DoesNotExist: CartQuantity matching query does not exist.
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What happens when you try CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True)[-1] or when you try converting the queryset to a list?

Comment: I get an error saying i can't index negative numbers or something like that. And how can I convert it to a list?

Comment: filtered_data = CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True)

filtered_data = list(filtered_data)

Comment: You can also try CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True).last()