# CartQuantity matching query does not exist ERROR

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm trying to get the newest/latest number in a query set:

I use this codeline for that:

```
CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True).get(pk=-1)
```

This is how the queryset looks like:

```
<bound method QuerySet.last of <QuerySet [4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5, 14, 10, 12]>>  # need last number(12)
```

I tried the code above but I get an Error message:

> store.models.CartQuantity.DoesNotExist: CartQuantity matching query does not exist.

This is my **models**:

```
class CartQuantity(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    cquantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
```

Does anyone know how to fix the error or another way of getting the newest number(in this case number 12 in the query set)?

Comment: try ```pk[-1]```

Comment: like this: CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True).get(pk[-1])?

Comment: @04k it doesn't work. I get an error: NameError: name 'pk' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True)[-1]`

or

`CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True).last()`

or

`CartQuantity.objects.filter(customer=customer).values_list('cquantity', flat=True).reverse()[0]`